# How to call a method into an AsyncTask class from outside?

Tags: android, sockets, android-asynctask

I have two simple classes:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    NetworkTask task;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        [...]       
        task = new NetworkTask();
        task.execute();
    }

public void myClickHandler(View view) {
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
            // Why this line crash?
            task.connection("127.0.0.1");
        break;
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
public class NetworkTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    Socket sock;
    volatile boolean running = true;

    public int connection(String url){
        try{
            sock = new Socket(url, 4567)
        }
        catch (IOException ex){
            Logger.getLogger(NetworkTask.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            return -1;
        }
    }

    public String doInBackground(String... strings) {

        // If I do this, it works well
        //connection(127.0.0.1);

        while(running)
        {
            [...]
        }

        return null;
    }   
}
```

As I commented when I call connection method from outside of the AsyncTask method, the app crashes more particulary « sock = new Socket(...) » line. But when connection call is done inside the AsynTask method socket is created.
I don't understand why.

What's happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because when you do

```
task.connection("127.0.0.1");
```

You are still working in the main (UI) Thread - you're not using the AsyncTask properly. Instead you're using it like a normal class, and so, you get a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` on the new Android versions.

However when you call from `doInBackground()`, it means you started the AsyncTask via `execute` and the work  is done in a *separate* Thread, letting everything work as it should.

Keep in mind that if you are doing non-network stuff, you can still call from outside. However, I'd recommend keeping your AsyncTask depend on the outside as little as possible, since AsyncTasks only run once. You then have to make a new instance if you want to do more work, which means if you depend on setter methods or similar, you have to make sure you call those methods again, which makes this simple class more complex than needed.

For a good, to the point explanation of how to use an AsyncTask, [this](http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/03/17/understanding-asynctask-once-and-forever/) is a pretty good source. And of course the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Comment: Ok thank you I understand. And so how to call a method from AsyncTask in order to run it into the "good" thread?

Comment: @Flow you used `task.execute()` in your code. That's how you do it the right way. `execute()` will take care of running the AsyncTask code in the non-UI thead. Also remember that you can supply arguments to `execute()` that get passed to `doInBackground()`. So you can still specify the URL from outside the AsyncTask.

Comment: Sure but I don't hardly have to do the connection as soon as main loop is launched... In this case, I may create the new socket long time after execute() has been called while main loop is running. You see what I mean?

Comment: @Flow Unfortunately I don't see what you mean. AsyncTasks (to me) are meant to have linear execution - do something in the background, then publish back to UI Thread once you're done. If you want to multithread, I'd say actually use separate `Thread`s/`Runnable`s.

Comment: Ok I understand better. In fact, AsyncTask is not suitable to my use. Anyway thank you very much for your responses!